# interaction.plot, change size of trace.label

Tags: r, plot

How do I change the size of the trace label, need to make it bigger. Is there any cex. function that I can use ?

This is my code

```
x <- interaction.plot(x.factor = data_flokvel$Vél.nr., 
                     trace.factor = data_flokvel$d , 
                     response = data_flokvel$Gallar.., 
                     fun = mean, type = "b", fixed = TRUE,legend = TRUE,
                     col= c(1:6),lwd = 3, cex.lab= 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5, 
                     cex.main = 1.5,lty = 1, ylab = "Flökunargallahlutfall (%)", 
                     xlab = "Vél númer", trace.label = "Þyngd karfa í kg")
```

I am using Rstudio 0.99

---

and a reproducible example:

```
with(ToothGrowth, interaction.plot(dose, supp, len, fixed = TRUE) ))
```

Comment: show your code here and then ask where are you stuck. Also for which language, version you are asking, choose those tags.

Comment: it looks like the label is hard coded with no option to alter the size - maybe try suppressing the label, and then add it manually using `text` (but then you need to mess about with coordinates) (ps it s good to add an example to your question, and the help age for `?interaction.plot `gives one: `with(ToothGrowth, 
interaction.plot(dose, supp, len, fixed = TRUE)
)`)

Comment: ... actually the trace.label (legend title) can be suppressed by setting legend=FALSE, then you can try adding it manually